# Set Android screen brightness in Kotlin in one line (versus Java)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screen-brightness

To set a minimum screen brightness in Android Java:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

To change screen brightness in Android Kotlin:

```
val lp = this.window.attributes
lp.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF
this.window.attributes = lp
```

However (as a beginner in Kotlin), I was surprised to see that this one line also works:

```
window.attributes.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF
```

Why does this work? Are there any unwanted side effects with this code?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this one-line piece won't work. You can open it in IDE to see that it translates approximately to

```
val lp = this.window.attributes
lp.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF
// this.window.attributes = lp — this one isn't called, explanation below
```

Kotlin won't do all nested `set*` calls for you, so it won't call `this.window.setAttributes()` method. And all the code that applies changes to actual window is triggered by this call.

Comment: This is the right answer. The highest upvoted answer it just wrong unfortunately. The thing that is surprising though is that the one-liner will work ni some cases (like onCreate). I assume that is something to do with the parameters being explicitly applied in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to update a single parameter from an Activity would be something like this in Kotlin:

```
    window.attributes = window.attributes.apply {
        screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF
    }
```

This is because you'll need to get the current LayoutParams from `android.view.getAttributes()`, update the screenBrightness value, and then call `android.view.setAttributes()` with the updated LayoutParams.

Answer (score 1):

As told by OleGG, I tried to do it in "one-line mode", but without any result.
I share with you the only thing that worked for me every single time in API 16 (or greater), using a SeekBar.

I have a companion object in the `SettingsActivity`

```
companion object {
    private const val WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION = 100
    private const val MAX_BRIGHTNESS = 255
    private const val MIN_BRIGHTNESS = 20
}
```

In in the `onCreate()` of `SettingsActivity`, I call

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL)
skb_brightness.max = MAX_BRIGHTNESS
skb_brightness.progress = AppPreferences.getInstance(this).brightnessKey
```

Then I create my listener like this:

```
object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    var brightnessProgress = 0

    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        brightnessProgress = map(progress, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS, MIN_BRIGHTNESS, MAX_BRIGHTNESS)

        if (hasPermissionsToWriteSettings(this@SettingsActivity)) {
            Settings.System.putInt(this@SettingsActivity.contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightnessProgress)
            // Do not write this in one-line, won't work
            val lp = this@SettingsActivity.window.attributes
            lp.screenBrightness = brightnessProgress.toFloat() / 255
            this@SettingsActivity.window.attributes = lp
        }
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) { }

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        AppPreferences.getInstance(this@SettingsActivity).brightnessKey = brightnessProgress
    }
}
```

Where `hasPermissionsToWriteSettings(this@SettingsActivity)` is a method that checks if I have permission to do that.

```
private fun hasPermissionsToWriteSettings(context: Activity): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Settings.System.canWrite(context)
    } else {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

The map function is for mapping the min value:

```
private fun map(currentValue: Int, inputMin: Int, inputMax: Int, outputMin: Int, outputMax: Int): Int {
    return (currentValue - inputMin) * (outputMax - outputMin) / (inputMax - inputMin) + outputMin
}
```

And the `AppPreferences` is my helper class to store the value of the brightness in the key-value shared-preferences. It does just this `(BRIGHTNESS_CONTROL_KEY = "brightnessControlValue", DEFAULT_BRIGHTNESS = 100)`:

```
var brightnessKey: Int
    get() = sharedPreferences.getInt(BRIGHTNESS_CONTROL_KEY, DEFAULT_BRIGHTNESS)
    set(value) = sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(BRIGHTNESS_CONTROL_KEY, value).apply()
```

I added also in the `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

...event if Android Studio tolds me that's wrong. Without this, I cannot change brightness.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I was just wondering how your AppPreferences class looks like, feels very clean the way you've solved this

Comment: @LosKayos since comments are limited, I posted my class on pastebin, here: https://pastebin.com/q53bX7hT

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! It seems like this code doesn't check nowhere the start-brightness of the user. The SeekBar is always set to 0 instead of the current value. Did you handle that in your final code?

Comment: @LosKayos check out this: https://pastebin.com/hPxqE26X . I tried to add all usefull things that happens inside my activity. I have a companion object with some static values. In the onCreate method I have a button that is active, if permission to WRITE_SETTINGS are not granted. On button press, it asks for permissions and set some options. Then, immediatly under the button listener I have all the logic of the seekbar.

Comment: I totally forgot about map fun, I added it in the end of the pastebin